# Why does this \label split preceding section headings?

Tags: page-breaking

I define sectioning commands `\task` and `\subtask` similar to the ones in the MWE below. Somehow, placing a `\label` behind a `\task` and `\subtask` causes LaTeX to allow a page break between the two. Without the `\label`, the page break occurs before the `\task` (as it should).

Why is that?

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% create the sectioning commands \task and \subtask
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
    style=section, level=1, afterskip=1sp plus .2ex, beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex, font=\Large, indent=0em, tocindent=0em, tocnumwidth=1.5em%
    ]{task}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
    style=section, level=2, counterwithin=task, afterskip=-0em, beforeskip=-2ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex, font=\Large, indent=0em, tocindent=2em, tocnumwidth=0em%
    ]{subtask}

\begin{document}

\task{one}
foo\\[47em]
bar

% here, the pagebreak occurs before the \task
\task{two}
\subtask{three}
baz

\clearpage

\task{one}
foo\\[47em]
bar

% here, the pagebreak occurs between the \task and the \subtask
\task{two}
\subtask{three}\label{asdf}
baz

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's generally safer to put a label in a heading or caption rather than after it

Comment: This problem is independent from KOMA-Script. If you use `\subsubsection` instead of `\task` and `\paragraph` instead of `\subtask` you will have exact the same with `article` instead of `scrartcl`. An alternative to David's suggestion would be to add `\leavemode` before `\label`.